# Nodejs HTTP request fails with some character

Tags: node.js, http, request

I am saving my data using HTTP request and its working fine. This is following my code:

```
var data = {
    title: request.body.title,
    description: request.body.description
};

var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
logger.debug(dataString);

var options = {
    hostname: config.hostName,
    port: config.defaultPort,
    path: '/api/save',
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': dataString.length,
        'authToken': token
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var dataStr = '';

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        dataStr += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        var res_data = JSON.parse(dataStr);
        if (res_data.status === "success") {
            response.note = JSON.parse(dataStr);
            callback(null, response);
        } else if(res_data.status === "failure") {
            callback(res_data.message, response);
        }
    });
});
req.write(dataString);
req.end();
req.on('error', function (e) {
    logger.error('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    //callback('problem with request: ' + e.message, null, null);
});
```

But if any `title` or `description` having character `’` its giving me error `socket hang up` and request fails. Why `’` character causing problem.

Working solution: i have using `encodeURIComponent()` before sending request and `decodeURIComponent()` after receiving request data, Then its working. Problem with this solution every where i am sending and receiving request data i have to `encode` and `decode`.

Is there is any better solution of this situation?

Comment: Stringify() generally requires UTF-8 encoded data, where is the `’` coming from and are you sure it is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the ' character?

Comment: @Pekka웃 actually i have form where user can enter title and description and when user copy paste from somewhere else and if it contains `’`. I am getting this error and i am not using any encoding. Interesting fact is this if i don't use HTTP request its working but with HTTP request its giving error.

Comment: @cs04iz1 how to escape this?

Comment: Don't escape it, fix the underlying problem instead. What encoding is the form using? Is the page set to UTF-8 in the browser?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i have already set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in HTML head.

Comment: Double-check. Look in the browser's encoding menu to make sure that the page containing the form is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: How to check in browser's what encoding page is using? @Pekka웃. In firefox its showing `Unicode` in character encoding option.